# JHipster vs MEAN-Stack vs MERN-Stack

Tags: reactjs, mean-stack, jhipster, progressive-web-apps, mern

I am familiar with developing AngularJS and Angular 2/4 UIs utilizing JHipster 4's JPA CRUD scaffolding but it feels unnatural.  And I think developing MEAN-Stack UIs is the path of highest productivity.

How much refactoring is involved utilizing MEAN-Stack UIs with JHipster JPA (MongoDB) and Angular scaffolding?

Also, if using JHipster's new React support, how much refactoring is required to utilize MERN-Stack UIs with JHipster JPA (MongoDB) and React scaffolding?

Oh, I forget to mention my development target is PWAs (Progressive Web Apps) aka mobile first design.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow, your question is too broad and primarily opinionated, see https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to fork the [jHipster generator](https://github.com/jhipster/generator-jhipster), add your own templates for `mongodb`, `express.js` and `nodejs`.

The server side templates are mostly in `generators/entity-server/templates`, and `generators/server/templates`. These template files are written as EJS templates ([EJS](http://www.embeddedjs.com/)).

One of the steps during the app generation is to create JSON files from the JDL file. You can run just the json creation using a command like this:

```
yo jhipster:import-jdl jhipster-jdl.jh --db=mysql --json-only=true
```

The JSON files will get created in `.jhipster` folder (note the "." in front which makes the folder hidden) under your project. 
Create your own sub-generators similar to the "server" and "entity-server" sub-generators, that use the generated JSON. The templates will have `JavaScript` that uses `nodejs`, `express.js` and `mongodb`, instead of `Java` with `JPA`, and Spring Boot.

This is not going to be easy, although you could follow the JHipster code and create the sub-generators.
I guess someone might have already done all this in one of the forks from JHipster, in which case you might want to start from there.